# How to send embed with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send embed message to a discord channel but in this way it doesn't work, did you have any idea ?

```
@bot.command(
    name="my_first_command",
    description="This is the first command I made!",
    scope=[GUILD_ID],
)
async def my_first_command(ctx):
embed1 = discord.Embed(
        title=mob['name'],
        colour=0xE5E242,
        url=mob['url'],
        description="Famille: " + mob['type'],
    )
    embed1.set_image(url=mob['imgUrl'])
    embed1.add_field(name="Caractéristiques", value=stats, inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed = embed1)
```

I got :

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<my_first_command() done, defined at bot.py:18> exception=TypeError("send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'embed'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 40, in my_first_command
    await ctx.send(embed = embed1)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/interactions/client/context.py", line 445, in send
    payload = await super().send(content, **kwargs)
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'embed'
```

Comment: Which documentation states that `Context.send()` takes an `embed` kwarg?

Comment: I follow theses steps https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107400/discord.Embed and other in StackOverflow

Comment: This isn't dpy.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)? It probably expects a necessary argument, `content` - the text message. Also, check your (`embed1 = ...`'s) indentation.

Comment: @Nayon This is not documentation and is not for the same library you are using. Take a look at the [official documentation for `interactions.py`](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify only the embed, then Python has to find out for itself which parameter it fits to. So try that:

```py
@bot.command(
    name="my_first_command",
    description="This is the first command I made!",
    scope=[GUILD_ID],
)
async def my_first_command(ctx):
embed1 = discord.Embed(
        title=mob['name'],
        colour=0xE5E242,
        url=mob['url'],
        description="Famille: " + mob['type'],
    )
    embed1.set_image(url=mob['imgUrl'])
    embed1.add_field(name="Caractéristiques", value=stats, inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed1)
```

Comment: It does not work, I have this : TypeError: Object of type Embed is not JSON serializable